# Import signingConfigs from multiple external files in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

We are using Flavors to create OEM-Versions of our App. Each Flavor is defined in an extra file (working fine) and each of the Flavor should have its own SigningConfig defined in an seperate file, too. But the approach used by the Flavors itself don't work with the SigningConfigs. Here is what's in the various files:

**build.gradle**

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    release { /* */ }

    /* Find and apply all Signing-Configs for Branding of App */
    project.file('oem-gradle-includes').listFiles().findAll {
        it.name.endsWith('.signing')
    }.collect {
        apply from: it /* Apply the signingConfig defined in each File */
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample.signing**

```
/* SigningConfig for SampleOEM-App */
android {
    signingConfigs {
            oemSample {
                    storeFile file('oem-gradle-includes/OEMSample.keystore')
        keyAlias "oemsample"
        storePassword "SuperSecretStorePassword"
        keyPassword "OnePasswordToRuleThemAll"
            }
    }
}
```

Sync Project with Gradle Files works fine (= no error) but when looking at Signing tab of Project Structure I see `project.file('oem-gradle-includes').listFiles().findAll {it.name.endsWith('.signing')}.collect` instead of expected `oemSample`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Another solution to achieve what (SigningConfig imported from external files) I want?